# convert string to json encodable and make sure it contains only utf-8 characters - PHP

Tags: php, json, string, encoding, utf-8

I am reading some emails and fetch the body content and perform `json_encode()` on it to send to another API. The problem is I am getting

> json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument.

Then I try to clean the string before `json_encode()` using

`$msg = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $msg);`

Again leads to

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

and returning false as the result.

Is there any workaround to clean a string and perform `json_encode()` without leading to any issues even though there are non-utf8 characters ? I am okay to remove all the non-utf8 characters

Comment: Have you looked inside source of email you are importing. There should be some charset headers like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-2"`. Maby there are some non utf-8 encodings used inside email and you should convert it first to utf-8?

Comment: okay I figured it out. https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8